# How to dataBind spreadSheet (SpreadJS) to a server side bean

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, primefaces, spreadjs

I have built a Spring WebMVC App with Primefaces. This app contains a list of nodes which can be dragged into the spreadSheet (I m working with SpreadJS). Behind each node there is a model and a bean. Evey node has a name and an input type. For example the node can be comboBox or simple input or input date ... . I need to do the synchronization between the node value and its value in the spreadSheet and aim-versa (communication between the primefaces component and spreadJS). for that i decide to load the spread from a json file. i didn t find the best way to do this communication because i can not add a parameter to the json file to add the id of the node after dragging it and when i change the json (which is server side), the refresh of the spreadSheet can t detect the changes that i made in the json file. How can i do this synchrnisation ?

Thanks in advance.

This is the function which load the spreadSheet from the json:

```
window.onload = function() {
            spread = new GC.Spread.Sheets.Workbook(document.getElementById("ss"));
            var sheet = spread.getActiveSheet();
            $.ajax({
                url: "spread.json",
                datatype: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    spread.fromJSON(JSON.parse(data));
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Exception:' + ex);
                }
            });
        };
```

Please find the example below :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9pVw.png)

How to synchronise the value of the input with its cell in the spreadSheet ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain how this is PrimeFaces related?